# mostrar un div sobrepuesto al div que se da click con javascript

Tags: javascript

¿Como puedo mostrar un div sobrepuesto al div que el usuario da click?, la estructura html contiene divs con clase box y dentro un div con clase interno, en primera instancia el div interno está oculto con un display => none dentro del css, entonces, lo que quiero es que cuando el usuario de click sobre un div con clase box se muestre de forma sobrepuesta el div interno pero solo el que está ubicado dentro del div al que se está dando click, ejemplo:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="interno"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="interno"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="interno"></div>
</div>
<script>  
var mostrar = document.getElementsClassName("box");
mostrar.addEventListener("onclick", arte);
function arte()
{
  document.getElementsClassName("interno").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

El problema que tengo es que al no conocer el id que identifica al div con clase box no le puedo ser especifico al javascript, en lugar de mostrarme solo el div interno al que doy click me muestra todos los divs interno.

¿Que puedo hacer para solucionar este problema?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Añade un parámetro a la función como te muestro abajo. He cambiado un poco el código para que se viera mejor. Además creo que tenías algún fallo, por ejemplo `getElementsClassName` no existe, debería de ser `getElementsByClassName`y además para poder añadir el evento a cada div deberías de recorrer `mostrar` :

```js
var mostrar = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
for(let i = 0; i < mostrar.length; i++) {
//aquí ademas de añadir el evnto, le paso a la función el propio div
  mostrar[i].addEventListener("click", function() {arte(mostrar[i])})
}
function arte(ad){
  ad.getElementsByClassName("interno")[0].style.display = "block"; 
      }
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background-color:blue;width:30px;height:30px">
  <div class="interno" style="background-color:red;width:30px;height:30px;display:none"></div>
</div>
<div class="box" style="background-color:blue;width:30px;height:30px">
  <div class="interno" style="background-color:red;width:30px;height:30px;display:none"></div>
</div>
<div class="box" style="background-color:blue;width:30px;height:30px">
  <div class="interno" style="background-color:red;width:30px;height:30px;display:none"></div>
</div>
```

Espero que sea lo que buscabas,
Un saludo!